# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{2+(-1)^k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I first I tried to use Comparison Test with $\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{2+(-1)^k}} \le \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ but I think Comparison Test only works with series with positive terms. Then I tried Alternating Series Test, but the sequence $\frac {1}{k^{2+(-1)^k}}$ is not decreasing for small values of $k$ and I don't think it will be decreasing for large $k$ either. How can I proceed with this problem?

Comment: The general term is $\displaystyle\frac1k$ for odd $k$ and $\displaystyle-\frac1{k^3}$ for even $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the non-negative terms diverges and the sum of the negative terms converges. Therefore the series diverges to $\infty$: namely, if you call $a_k=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{2+(-1)^k}}$ and $L=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$, then eventually $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\ge L+\varepsilon_n+\sum_{1\le 2k\le n} a_{2k}$$ with $\varepsilon_n\to 0$. A slight variation works for the general case where the subsequence of all the negative terms ended up being a generic $\left\{a_{n_k}\right\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: So, should I prove by first separating the series into sum two series (odd and even indexed) and then show one of them is diverging and the other is converging?

Comment: @user666150 Essentially yes, plus proving an estimate along the lines of what I've written and producing a convincing argument that it should imply divergence to $-\infty$.